# Is there a way to connect two programs located on the same machine in java?

Tags: java

I am asking if there is a way to connect 2 programs on the same machine and exchange data. I tried to do this with sockets giving them IP as localhost, but I think there would be another way to do that.

Comment: keyword to google: IPC

Comment: There are other ways ... but sockets are probably the simplest way to do it in Java.  What is your reason to want something different?

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach of using sockets is a good one to share the objects between two programs.

In more detail, to connect two programs, with out data storage good choice is to use RMI Socket Communication or Java messaging service -
[Socket Communications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html).

Answer (score 0):

If by 2 programs you mean 2 programs running in Java, then **every Java program is started in its own independent JVM**. So standard thread or process communication techniques will not work.

**The easiest way is to use Sockets.**

Comment: "So standard thread or process communication techniques will not work." Thread - no, of course. But standard inter-process communication will of course work, sockets being one of them.